Invalid User pool ID provided AWS cognito + NextJS 14
I was trying to setup cognito with next-14 and I created a user pool and a user pool client. I got both the user_pool_id and the user_pool_client_id. My Auth code is really simple...
Here's how I'm initialising Cognito
'use client';

import { Amplify, type ResourcesConfig } from 'aws-amplify';

export const authConfig: ResourcesConfig['Auth'] = {
    Cognito: {
        userPoolId: String(process.env.NUANCE_PUB_USERPOOL_ID),
        userPoolClientId: String(process.env.NUANCE_PUB_USERPOOL_CLIENT_ID),
    },
};

Amplify.configure(
    {
        Auth: authConfig,
    },
    { ssr: true }
);

export default function ConfigureAmplifyClientSide() {
  // TODO: remove log.
  console.log(process.env.NUANCE_PUB_USERPOOL_ID)
  return null;
}

My Auth Class
import {
    signUp,
    confirmSignUp,
    signIn,
    signOut,
    resendSignUpCode,
} from 'aws-amplify/auth';

export async function handleSignUp(
    prevState: string | undefined,
    formData: FormData
)

export async function handleSendEmailVerificationCode(
    prevState: { message: string; errorMessage: string },
    formData: FormData
)
 
export async function handleConfirmSignUp(
    prevState: string | undefined,
    formData: FormData
)

// More functions here for signout and signin. 

I'm getting the error "Invalid User pool id provided".. below is the complete stack.
InvalidUserPoolId: Invalid user pool id provided.
at getRegionFromUserPoolId (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/dist/esm/foundation/parsers/regionParsers.mjs:17:15)
at signUp (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/dist/esm/providers/cognito/apis/signUp.mjs:89:111)
at handleSignUp (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/lib/services/service.authentication.ts:23:118)
at runFormStateAction (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12204:23)
at dispatchFormState (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12177:5)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12837:12)
at startTransition (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12738:25)
at startHostTransition (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12834:3)
at submitForm (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:29585:5)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20565:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20614:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20689:29)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20703:25)
at executeDispatch (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32128:3)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32160:7)
at processDispatchQueue (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32173:5)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32184:3)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32374:12)
at batchedUpdates$1 (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24953:12)
at batchedUpdates (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:28844:12)
at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:32373:3)
at dispatchEvent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30141:5)
at dispatchDiscreteEvent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:30112:5)

I've checked my configurations and everything seems fine to me. I'm trying to run this on localhost and it should technically work. I've also verified that the env variables are properly being set.
Not sure what is the issue here.
